# How to make Valgrind error on certain nonleak warnings?

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

Running Valgrind (on the default Memcheck tool) sometimes gives me warnings like

```
==2339== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close()
```

I would like to make these warnings into hard errors. However, I cannot find a way to do it from [the documentation](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html), which only specifies that you can filter which memory leaks to be errors. Is there any way to get Valgrind to error for me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not currently possible.

These are generated in the Valgrind core but only enabled in memcheck and helgrind and when -v is specifed. There is some code for core errors but it no longer does anything.